# sending a message in a interval and then deletes it

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to make a command that sends a message and then deletes it using a interval every 30 seconds.
But it's spamming and deleting the same time in stead of the 30 seconds wait time.

```
if (message.content.startsWith(botconfig.prefix + 'test')) {
  var testChannel = bot.channels.find(channel => channel.id === '657187838038769685');
      setInterval(() => {
          testChannel.send("Yay").then(msg => {
            msg.delete(1000)

      }, 30000)
    })
```

Comment: Do you want to send a new message every 30 seconds, then delete it 30 seconds later, or do you want to send a message on command, then delete it 30 seconds later?

Comment: No sends a message, delete it immediately and then after 30 sec again

Comment: The issue might be you're missing a bracket after msg.delete(1000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not indented as expected. This is the right way:

```js
if (message.content.startsWith(botconfig.prefix + 'test')) {
  var testChannel = bot.channels.find(channel => channel.id === '657187838038769685');
      setInterval(() => {
          testChannel.send("Yay").then(msg => {
            msg.delete(1000)

      });
    }, 30000)
```

I reserved two line, to show you what was the problem, but your indentation is not very readable so you should try to make it a bit cleaner...